# In vuejs, quoting variables in HTML element attribute doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

Here is the code:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in detail" :key="item.name" class="[[ item.name ]]">
  <td>[[ index + 1 ]]</td>
  <td>[[ item.name ]]</td>
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<tr class="[[ item.name ]]">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Job</td>
</tr>
<tr class="[[ item.name ]]">
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Jesse</td>
</tr>
<tr class="[[ item.name ]]">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Wazert</td>
</tr>
```

The `class="[[ item.name ]]"` just don't change. What I expect is:

```
<tr class="Job">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Job</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Jesse">
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Jesse</td>
</tr>
<tr class="Wazert">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Wazert</td>
</tr>
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Where did you read about using square brackets? [The documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) is pretty clear and also covers how to bind data to attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing **Square bracket** not worked in vue.js you need to use `interpolation` for binding the data dynamically.

So you need to use like For Example

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr v-for="(item, index) in detail" :key="item.name" :class="item.name">
      <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
data: function () {
  return {
    detail: [{ name: "Job" }, { name: "Jesse" }, { name: "Wazert" }],
  };
},
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-buck-37bx8?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) you can play with code

Comment: thanks a lot for the codesandbox link. So if I want to change `:class` to `:data-custom`, that works too? Sorry I can't find a place to rerun the modified code on codesandbox.

Comment: no use only `:class` because this is built in class for binding dynamic class after modified in codesandbox press CTRL + S and check if not work then create one and paste my code there and check

Comment: thanks for the feedback, so what about data-custom? how could I do that if I don't want to use `class`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `class-binding` and `interpolate` the data:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({ 
    detail: [ { name: "Job" }, { name: "Jesse" }, { name: "Wazert" } ] 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in detail" :key="item.name" :class="item.name">
      <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```